# is it any documentation for mercurial 'summary' command output?

Tags: mercurial

My scripts are using mercurial command-line and parse output, and now i'm a bit confised about 'summary' command output. For `commit` it writes `(clean)` in some cases, like this:

```
$ hg summary
branch: default
commit: 2 unknown (clean)
update: (current)
```

And sometimes it don't writes `(clean)`:

```
$ hg summary
branch: default
commit: 1 modified, 2 unknown
update: (current)
```

Is it any documentation available that explains meaning of this `(clean)` text? Or it is implementation specific and mercurial output is not intended to be parsed via scripts?

I'm also curious what are `(current)`, `(update)` etc, but they seems not very important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#summary) for the command (`hg help summary`) is admittedly terse. You can, however, look at the implementation of `hg summary` [here](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/tip/mercurial/commands.py#l5520) to understand what the output means.

Comment: In the meantime the source has been changed so the [new link is here](http://www.selenic.com/hg/file/tip/mercurial/commands.py#l5396)

Comment: And now you can take a look at the `summary` function in the `commands.py` file [here](http://hg.intevation.org/mercurial/crew-stable/file/b930d4ef7739/mercurial/commands.py#L5927). (The [main repository](https://selenic.com/hg) seems to be down at the moment.)

Answer (score 0):

What the `summary` command calls "commit status" is the status of files in the repository as per `hg status`, but shows a count instead of a list. In your case, `(clean)` means there are no added, modified, untracked or ignored files.